# Mac OS X Sandbox: shared access to user selected files

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I have an application, which installs an agent, and I want the agent to be able to access the files, selected by the user in the application by using `NSOpenPanel`.

What is the best method of doing this in Mac OS Sandbox ?

Comment: The agent(another process) is started by the app, which can also put an plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ in order to make that process run all the time, when the user is loged in.

Comment: AFAIK, a child process of a sandboxed app shares the sandboxed environment so you need to store a security-scoped-bookmark to the file (or directory holding the file) before starting the child process.  I haven't tried this myself (yet) but will be shortly...

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but when the agent is started by launchd, it can't use the security-scoped-bookmark, only the app can used them.

Comment: Are you able to start the agent yourself using `posix_spawn()`?  I think (I hope) that will work.  The alternative is to use XPC, which you might be able to use to pass the bookmark across.  I will be interested in your progress.

Comment: How is this going; I am interested in your progress.

Comment: I used the SMLoginItemSetEnabled() function to launch the 'agent'. I was surprised to see that, the login item is restarted after a crash (in the agent and daemon documentation, they say that login items are not managed by launchd), which was very important for my app to work as designed.

Comment: The problem of sharing the user selected files between the main app and the helper is not solved yet. I want to share the security scope bookmarks between the main app and the agent, but I was not able to do this, even if the app and the agent are in the same group (I see there are some problems with group application). Probably I will request the right to acces the files I need from the agent, which will be very ugly, but I don't see other solution (there are to many files to copy them in a common directory).

Comment: @usain: Your problem is resolved??? I'm also interesting it. How to share access to user selected files?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach for having a process that runs when the user is logged in is to use SMLoginItemSetEnabled(). You can do so, by putting the agent bundle inside the login item folder of the Main App bundle (MainApp/Contents/Library/LoginItems/Agent).

Then, starting from OS X 10.7.4, [application-groups entitlements](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) can be used so that both your main app and your agent can share this entitlement allowing it to do IPC and to share access to a group container ( ~/Library/Group Containers/.

Then, when the user selects files using NSOpenPanel, you can ask the UI to copy the selected files into the group containers so that the agent can then process them.

Comment: So there is not possible, to share the security scoped bookmarks, between the main application and the helper even if they are in the same application group.

Comment: usain, the documentation doesn't mention anything about security-scope bookmarks and application groups entitlements. If your agent doesn't need a persistent access to the user selected file, try to use a standard URL bookmark instead and pass it to your helper app using an IPC mechanism (e.g XPC connections). I didn't test it but I've read somewhere that it works.

Comment: I also read that, but in my case the helper stars at login, and in order to get the URL bookmark, it must start the app, which I don't think is a good approach. I can also get the bookmarks in the helper, but I think opening an window from the helper when the app is running is confusing for the user. I really don't know which approach is the best in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Group Containers are not really supported in 10.7.5 since containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier is only supported in 10.8+.